# XLSX file via OpenXml SDK Both Valid and Invalid

Tags: openxml, xlsx, openxml-sdk

I have a program which exports a System.Data.DataTable to an XLSX / OpenXml Spreadsheet. Finally have it mostly working. However when opening the Spreadsheet in Excel, Excel complains about the file being invalid, and needing repair, giving this message...

> We found a problem with some content in . Do you want us to
>   try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of the
>   workbook, clik Yes.

If I click Yes, it comes back with this message...

[image]

Clicking the log file and opening that, just shows this...

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
        <logFileName>error268360_01.xml</logFileName>
        <summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\aabdi\AppData\Local\Temp\data.20190814.152538.xlsx'</summary>
        <repairedRecords>
            <repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</repairedRecord>
        </repairedRecords>
    </recoveryLog>
```

Obviously, we don't want to deploy this into a production environment like this. So I've been trying to figure out how to fix this. I threw together a quick little sample to validate the XML and show the errors, based on [this link from MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2010/03/04/validate-open-xml-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk-2-0/). But when I run the program and load the exact same XLSX document that Excel complains about, the Validator comes back saying that the file is perfectly Valid. So I'm not sure where else to go from there.

Any better tools for trying to validate my XLSX XML? Following is the complete code I'm using to generate the XLSX file. (Yes, it's in VB.NET, it's a legacy app.)

If I comment out the line in the `For Each dr As DataRow` loop, then the XLSX file opens fine in Excel, (just without any data). So it's something with the individual cells, but I'm not really DOING much with them. Setting a value and data type, and that's it.

I also tried replacing the `For Each` loop in `ConstructDataRow` with the following, but it still outputs the same "bad" XML...

```vb
        rv.Append(
            (From dc In dr.Table.Columns
             Select ConstructCell(
                 NVL(dr(dc.Ordinal), String.Empty),
                 MapSystemTypeToCellType(dc.DataType)
             )
            ).ToArray()
        )
```

Also tried replacing the call to `Append` with `AppendChild` for each cell too, but that didn't help either.

The zipped up XLSX file (erroring, with dummy data) is available here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KVVWEqH7VHMxwbRA-Pn807SXHZ32oJWR

**Full DataTable to Excel XLSX Code**

---

```vb
    #Region " ToExcel "
    <Extension>
    Public Function ToExcel(ByVal target As DataTable) As Attachment
        Dim filename = Path.GetTempFileName()
        Using doc As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)
            Dim data = New SheetData()

            Dim wbp = doc.AddWorkbookPart()
            wbp.Workbook = New Workbook()
            Dim wsp = wbp.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
            wsp.Worksheet = New Worksheet(data)

            Dim sheets = wbp.Workbook.AppendChild(New Sheets())
            Dim sheet = New Sheet() With {.Id = wbp.GetIdOfPart(wsp), .SheetId = 1, .Name = "Data"}
            sheets.Append(sheet)

            data.AppendChild(ConstructHeaderRow(target))
            For Each dr As DataRow In target.Rows
                data.AppendChild(ConstructDataRow(dr)) '// THIS LINE YIELDS THE BAD PARTS
            Next

            wbp.Workbook.Save()
        End Using

        Dim attachmentname As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename), $"data.{Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd.HHmmss")}.xlsx")
        File.Move(filename, attachmentname)
        Return New Attachment(attachmentname, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    End Function

    Private Function ConstructHeaderRow(dt As DataTable) As Row
        Dim rv = New Row()
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            rv.Append(ConstructCell(dc.ColumnName, CellValues.String))
        Next
        Return rv
    End Function

    Private Function ConstructDataRow(dr As DataRow) As Row
        Dim rv = New Row()
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dr.Table.Columns
            rv.Append(ConstructCell(NVL(dr(dc.Ordinal), String.Empty), MapSystemTypeToCellType(dc.DataType)))
        Next
        Return rv
    End Function

    Private Function ConstructCell(value As String, datatype As CellValues) As Cell
        Return New Cell() With {
        .CellValue = New CellValue(value),
        .DataType = datatype
        }
    End Function

    Private Function MapSystemTypeToCellType(t As System.Type) As CellValues
        Dim rv As CellValues
        Select Case True
            Case t Is GetType(String)
                rv = CellValues.String
            Case t Is GetType(Date)
                rv = CellValues.Date
            Case t Is GetType(Boolean)
                rv = CellValues.Boolean
            Case IsNumericType(t)
                rv = CellValues.Number
            Case Else
                rv = CellValues.String
        End Select

        Return rv
    End Function
    #End Region
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else coming in and finding this, I finally tracked this down to the `Cell.DataType`

Setting a value of `CellValues.Date` will cause Excel to want to "fix" the document. 
(apparently for dates, [the DataType should be NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-cells-in-a-spreadsheet), and `Date` was only used in Office 2010).

Also, if you specify a DataType of `CellValues.Boolean`, then the CellValue needs to be either 0 or 1. "true" / "false" will also cause Excel to want to "fix" your spreadsheet.

Also, Microsoft has a better validator tool already built for download here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Comment: Although MS' own validation tool can still report a document as perfectly valid, and yet still have Excel barf on it when you try to open it. 

Comment: Had a similar problem, this sorted it out. Thanks!

Comment: The download link no longer works. Anyone know the name of the file so I can google it?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - sheesh! Why would MS take away this tool?? ‍♂️ There is an OOXML validator extension for VS Code. You could check into that, and see if it works for your needs.

Comment: I did manage to find the tool on archive.org! Unfortunately, it tells me the file is perfectly fine, yet it still causes Excel to barf. So, not so useful in the end - good DIFF tool inside it though.