# Excel Insists that my OpenXml file has errors

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

Okay, I'm generating an Excel file from a DataTable. I generate the file and save it, no compilation or run-time errors. When I open the file in Excel though, it pops up the message:

> We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

So I click `Yes`. After a second or two, it comes up with the following message:

> Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.
>   Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml (Styles)
>   Click to view log file listing repairs: `C:\file\path\filename.xml`

but if you click through to open the log, it just says the same thing basically, with no additional details.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>error336080_01.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\my\file\path\data.xlsx'</summary>
    <repairedRecords>
        <repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)</repairedRecord>
    </repairedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

So, I figured Okay... I just found Microsoft's nifty little OOXML SDK Validator/Compare tool. So I open up the "bad" file in that, and run a `Validate`. It comes back with full success, and indicates that there are no errors in the file. So I'm not really sure what Excel is complaining about.
[image]

Additionally, after allowing Excel to "repair", and then finish opening the file, the worksheet is all styled and shown properly, and all the data filled in, and looks exactly as it is expected to look.
[image]

Here is my code that I am using to generate the OOXML stylesheet...
*(Yes, it's VB.NET, it's a legacy app.)*

```vb
Private Function ConstructStyleSheet() As Stylesheet
    Dim rv As Stylesheet = New Stylesheet()

    rv.AppendChild(New NumberingFormats(
        New NumberingFormat() With {.NumberFormatId = 0, .FormatCode = "General"},
        New NumberingFormat() With {.NumberFormatId = 5, .FormatCode = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
    ))

    rv.AppendChild(New Fonts(
        New Font(),
        New Font(New Bold())
    ))

    rv.AppendChild(New Borders(
        New Border(),
        New Border(New BottomBorder(New Color() With {.Auto = True}) With {.Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin})
    ))

    '// COMMENTING OUT THIS BLOCK (BUT LEAVING ALL ABOVE) YIELDS AN XLSX WITH NO ERRORS
    '// BUT OF COURSE, NO STYLING ON ANY CELLS, EITHER
    rv.AppendChild(New CellFormats(
        New CellFormat() With {.FontId = 0, .ApplyFont = True},
        New CellFormat() With {.FontId = 1, .BorderId = 1, .ApplyFont = True, .ApplyBorder = True},
        New CellFormat() With {.FontId = 0, .ApplyFont = True, .NumberFormatId = 5, .ApplyNumberFormat = True}
    ))

    Return rv
End Function
```

And here is the content of the `/xl/styles.xml` stylesheet...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <x:numFmts>
        <x:numFmt numFmtId="0" formatCode="General" />
        <x:numFmt numFmtId="5" formatCode="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
    </x:numFmts>
    <x:fonts>
        <x:font />
        <x:font>
            <x:b />
        </x:font>
    </x:fonts>
    <x:borders>
        <x:border />
        <x:border>
            <x:bottom style="thin">
                <x:color auto="1" />
            </x:bottom>
        </x:border>
    </x:borders>
    <x:cellXfs>
        <x:xf fontId="0" applyFont="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="1" borderId="1" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf numFmtId="5" fontId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" applyFont="1" />
    </x:cellXfs>
</x:styleSheet>
```

Comment: Is this question related to or different from your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502096/xlsx-file-via-openxml-sdk-both-valid-and-invalid ? FWIW Usually a good trouble-shooting step for these is to save the repaired file to a different name. Open the orignal file in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. Use the "Compare" functionality to open the repaired file. This will generate the XML that is different *and the code to generate* the repaired file from the original. This usually tells you enough to fix the problem.

Comment: It is related, but a different issue. I ultimately tracked that one down and fixed it (and answered the question). Hmm... I had looked at the compare, between saving it in Excel after repairing, but it is MASSIVELY different. Excel adds a LOT a LOT of other stuff and moves things around into all different places that the SDK doesn't put out when it generates the file. Hadn't thought of maybe being able to generate the code for just the Styles sections though from the compare. I'll have to look at that. Might get me a little closer.

Comment: What makes it especially frustrating is that the SDK Validator says that the output file is 100% perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, in that case I'd first concentrate on comparing the xml for the styles in both files. Once you see how that XML differs it might be easier to track down. I'm not that famiiliar with the Excel Open XML, my area is more Word, but something I noticed in that other question was that *maybe* you're running into a difference in "strictness" - a change in the later versions of Open XML that older versions of the Office application may have trouble with. That's not something a validator would catch. I don't remember exactly what it was that made me think that, though...

Comment: @CindyMeister - finally tracked it down; thanks. There were a LOT of differences, went through one by one adding them in until it worked. Will add an answer detailing the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked this one down after some work too, and posting the answer here for posterity.

Turns out Excel **NEEDS** you to put Fill Styles in the output file, even if you aren't using any fill styles in any of your cells.

```vb
    Private Function ConstructStyleSheet() As Stylesheet
        Dim rv As Stylesheet = New Stylesheet()

        rv.AppendChild(New NumberingFormats(
            New NumberingFormat() With {.NumberFormatId = 5, .FormatCode = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"}
        ) With {.Count = 1})

        rv.AppendChild(New Fonts(
            New Font(),
            New Font(New Bold())
        ) With {.Count = 2})

        '// ===== NEW SECTION =====
        rv.AppendChild(New Fills(
            New Fill(New PatternFill() With {.PatternType = PatternValues.None}),
            New Fill(New PatternFill() With {.PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125})
        ) With {.Count = 2})
        '\\ =======================

        rv.AppendChild(New Borders(
            New Border(),
            New Border(New BottomBorder(New Color() With {.Auto = True}) With {.Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin})
        ) With {.Count = 2})

        '// ===== THEN ALSO ADD THE .FillId = 0 ON ALL OF THE CellFormats
        rv.AppendChild(New CellFormats(
            New CellFormat() With {.FillId = 0, .BorderId = 0, .FontId = 0, .NumberFormatId = 0},
            New CellFormat() With {.FillId = 0, .ApplyBorder = True, .ApplyFont = True, .BorderId = 1, .FontId = 1, .NumberFormatId = 0},
            New CellFormat() With {.FillId = 0, .ApplyNumberFormat = True, .BorderId = 0, .NumberFormatId = 5, .FontId = 0, .ApplyFont = True}
        ) With {.Count = 3})

        Return rv
    End Function
```

After these two questions, clear moral of the story is that Excel (and I'm guessing the other Office apps too?) is ***EXTREMELY*** picky about the XML put out in the XLSX file, and you need to just spend a LOT of time debugging and tracking down stupid little things like this, even if they are things you don't actually need in your file.

Comment: FWIW Word is a bit more forgiving in some respects. The zip package is definitely less complicated. I know with Excel they ran into a lot of probems with file size (and thus efficiency/speed) which is why things are so cryptic and complex.